# Dynamically loading shared objects with/without version numbers

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

In a Linux program, I need to load a shared object called `libfoobar`. On my system, there's `libfoobar.so`, `libfoobar.so.0` and `libfoobar.so.0.0.0`. On another system with a different distribution installed, `libfoobar.so` does not exist, only the other two variants are available.

What is the correct filename I should be using when loading the shared object? Is it sufficient to try to load `libfoobar.so.0` on any system and bail out if that fails, or should I attempt to load the other variants?

Comment: What is exactly that `libfoobar`? A [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))  (following *specific* conventions dictated by the main program) or an "ordinary" library? Why do you `dlopen` it? Please **edit your question** to give a lot more details. They matter.

Comment: Read [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (by Drepper).

Comment: Maybe use `-Wl,-R,<path>` and `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` so the link-loader handles it for you. Also see [What exactly does --enable-new-dtags do?](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2005-04/msg00052.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libfoobar.so.0` and `libfoobar.so.0.0.0` are supposed to be symlinks which at some level point to `libfoobar.so`. If you found a system where only those symlinks exist but not `libfoobar.so`, then the installation is broken on that system.

Besides that, it is up to you whether you want to use the symlink or the original filename.

Comment: There is `libfoobar.so.0.0.0`, which is a regular file, and `libfoobar.so.0`, a symlink to `libfoobar.so.0.0.0`. No `libfoobar.so`.

There are plenty of other .so files that follow the exact same scheme, without a plain `lib*.so` file. The installation is not broken, every app using these files works fine.

Comment: I see. (and checked on my system). Doing so the OS distribution is free to install multiple versions of the same library next to each other. I mean `libfoobar.so.0`, `libfoobar.so.1` and just use the symlink for minor versions.